# Print numbered list in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, set, for-in-loop

I am trying to print out a set of students in a class in a numbered list.

Here's the code I have

```
var spanish101: Set = ["Angela", "Declan", "Aldany", "Alex", "Sonny", "Alif", "Skyla"]
var german101: Set = ["Angela", "Alex", "Declan", "Kenny", "Cynara", "Adam"]
var advancedCalculus: Set = ["Cynara", "Gabby", "Angela", "Samantha", "Ana", "Aldany", "Galina", "Jasmine"]
var artHistory: Set = ["Samantha", "Vanessa", "Aldrian", "Cynara", "Kenny", "Declan", "Skyla"]
var englishLiterature: Set = ["Gabby", "Jasmine", "Alex", "Alif", "Aldrian", "Adam", "Angela"]
var computerScience: Set = ["Galina", "Kenny", "Sonny", "Alex", "Skyla"]
 
var allStudents: Set = spanish101.union(german101).union(advancedCalculus).union(artHistory).union(englishLiterature).union(computerScience)


for students in allStudents
{
  print(students)
}
```

I've tried doing `print(students.count, students)`, but that just prints out random numbers.

Unsure of why and where those numbers come from. 
I've tried making a nested loop with for count in 1..<students.count , but that made the list print out 16 times.

I want the output to look like

```
1 studentName
2 studentName
3 studentName
4 studentName
...
16 studentName
```

Comment: `allStudents` is a Set`, so `students` is an element of the set, so it's a `String`, no? Set have no order, so you can't guarantee that `1 studentName` will always be the same.

Comment: Short variant `allStudents.enumerated().forEach { print("\($0 + 1) \($1)") }`

Comment: for (n, student) in zip(1..., allStudents) { print("\\(n) \\(student)") }

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
for anEnumerated in allStudents.enumerated() {
    print("\(anEnumerated.0) - \(anEnumerated.1)")
}
```

Or

```
for (anOffset, aStudent) in allStudents.enumerated() {
    print("\(anOffset) - \(aStudent)")
}
```

If you want to start at `1` instead of `0`, simply add `+ 1`: `(anOffset + 1)` or `\(anEnumerated.0 + 1)`

But note that `allStudents` is a `Set`, so there is no guaranteed order on the enumeration.

You could use an `Array` to sort `allStudents` or maybe a `OrderedSet` from [Swift-Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedSet.md).

Answer (score 0):

If you need sorting, then try using this solution:

```
allStudents
    .sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }) // Sorting
    .enumerated() // Numbering
    .forEach { // Cycle
        print("\($0 + 1) \($1)")
    }
```